# NumPy ndarray.all() vs np.all(ndarray) vs all(ndarray)

Tags: python, performance, numpy

What is the the difference between the three "all" methods in Python/NumPy? What is the reason for the performance difference? Is it true that ndarray.all() is always the fastest of the three?

Here is a timing test that I ran:

```
In [59]: a = np.full(100000, True, dtype=bool)

In [60]: timeit a.all()
The slowest run took 5.40 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.24 µs per loop

In [61]: timeit all(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop

In [62]: timeit np.all(a)
The slowest run took 5.54 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.41 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between `np.all(a)` and `a.all()` is simple:

- If `a` is a `numpy.array` then `np.all()` will simply call `a.all()`.
- If `a` is not a `numpy.array` the `np.all()` call will convert it to an `numpy.array` and then call `a.all()`. `a.all()` on the other hand will fail because `a` wasn't a `numpy.array` and therefore probably has no `all` method.

The difference between `np.all` and `all` is more complicated.

- The `all` function works on any iterable (including `list`, `set`s, `generators`, ...). `np.all` works only for `numpy.array`s (including everything that can be converted to a numpy array, i.e. `list`s and `tuple`s).
- `np.all` processes an `array` with specified data type, that makes it pretty efficient when comparing for `!= 0`. `all` however needs to evaluate `bool` for each item, that's much slower.
- processing arrays with python functions is pretty slow because each item in the array needs to be converted to a python object. `np.all` doesn't need to do that conversion.

Note that the timings depend also on the type of your `a`. If you process a python list `all` can be faster for relativly short lists. If you process an array, `np.all` and `a.all()` will be faster in almost all cases (except maybe for `object` arrays, but I won't go down that path, that way lies madness).

Comment: The Python `all` iterates on `a`.  `all(a)`, `all(iter(a))`, `all(list(a))`, `all(a.tolist())` all time about the same.  But `all` can short circuit.  Set `a[2]=False` and see very different times.

Comment: `np.all` also short-circuits, doesn't it? Also `all(a.tolist())` is significantly faster (2-3 times) than `all(a)` on my computer. That's mostly because the `tolist` method is optimized for wrapping the array as list of python objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a swing at this

- `np.all` is a generic function which will work with different data types, under the hood this probably looks for `ndarray.all` which is why it's slightly slower.
- `all` is a python bulit-in function see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all.
- `ndarray.all` is method of the 'numpy.ndarray' object, calling this directly may be faster.

Comment: Is there any obvious explanation for what's happening in the implementation that causes the slowdown?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that numpy's functions do more to evaluate an array element as a boolean, likely in some generic numeric-first way, while the builtin `all()` does nothing, since the elements are already booleans.

I wonder how different the results would be with integers of floats.

Comment: No the elements aren't `bool`s already. They are `numpy.bool_`s. While they behave similar (or identical) they are not identical `np.bool_ is not bool`