# Compare two lists one to one in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to compare each element of the two equal length lists.

```
import numpy as np

def comp_one2one(list1, list2):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list2[i] > list1[i]:
            tmp.append(True)
        else: 
            tmp.append(False)
    return np.any(tmp)
list1 = [10, 15, 20]
list2 = [50, 10, 15] 
> print(comp_one2one(list1,list2))
True
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient and more pythonic way of doing this operation?

Comment: Yes, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) `any(l2 > l1 for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2))`

Answer (score 1):

```
def comp_one2one(list1, list2):    
    return all(np.array(list1)>np.array(list2))
```

edit: I missed the greater than, but you can change that to anything.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi He has imported numpy, therefore I'm assuming that numpy will be used in part of the project so why not use it?

Comment: Fair enough. You might as well use `np.all()` then. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382396/843953

Answer (score 1):

Lik Pranav mentioned, you can zip the two lists together

```
list1 = [10, 15, 20]
list2 = [50, 10, 15] 
tmp = []
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    if l2 > l1:
        tmp.append(True)
    else: 
        tmp.append(False)
        
tmp
#[True, False, False]
```

Or you can try list comprehension

```
[l2>l1 for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2)]

#[True, False, False]
```

Comment: They return `np.any(tmp)` from the function, so you can also do `any(...)` without the brackets, because `any()` can take a generator expression.

Comment: Sure that makes sense, thank you. My intention was to comment on the core algorithm.